# Key Exchange and anonymity issue

Tags: key-exchange, anonymity

If Alice (sender) sends a private message embedded with public key of the Bob(recipient) through onion network, so in this key exchange, does Bob remains anonymous to Alice as Alice knows about the public key of Bob. So if we want to achieve mutual anonymity, how can we do that? Can we achieve mutual anonymity through this key exchange?

Comment: I suppose you'll have to state your question more precisely ... as it is, there is not enough detail. What kind of mix network are you using? How does the public key relates to who receives the message?

Answer (score 3):

You could cheat and use different keys for each recipient. That would work assuming the recipients don't know each other (and cannot compare keys).

Mix networks are by design hard to trace so it depends on the network.

EDIT:
Sending a message to Bob implies Alice knows how to find Bob in the first place, or knows someone who *knows* where Bob is, without Bob having to directly reveal his location to Alice. The Tor network has implemented this through [hidden services](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en) which guarantees that both Alice and Bob remain anonymous to each other. The webpage has some diagrams as well and explains how it works, but I won't go into much detail about it because your question isn't about Tor.

It is important to note that public key cryptography doesn't guarantee anonymity or privacy or protection from identification. It's not designed for it. It just protects a message. Tor has managed to do a decent job at protecting two parties who wish to talk to each other and is [reasonably mature](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwMr8Xl7JMQ) but mutual anonymity really depends on the (onion) network Alice and Bob are using - not on the PK scheme.

Answer (score 2):

If Alice didn't know who Bob was before, she still doesn't. All she knows is that she communicated with someone who has the private key corresponding with that public key, which presumably is the reason Bob has a public key.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So it means that we can use onion routing in P2P network for anonymous data transfer between two parties(Alice and Bob) such that requester(Alice) does not know about sender and sender does not know about requester?As I thought that with if we create a route from requester to sender through onion routers, the anonymity between two could not be achieved.

Comment: @Alexandera: Why wouldn't they be able to remain anonymous? All the communications are re-encrypted on each hop and unless lots of nodes are conspiring, nobody knows the whole path. (Even the node Alice is communicating directly with doesn't know it's communicating directly with Alice. For all it knows, Alice got the data from another node. Ditto for Bob's node, which has no idea it's the last node in the path.)

Comment: @ as for anonymity, i thought that requester should not know the identity of sender and sender should not know the identity of the requester.And that knowing the public key(or pseudonym), we can relate it with identity.

Comment: It means that the last node of Bob decrypts the packet and found out that there is no other router to forward the packet to, thus it transfers the unencrypted content to Bob,right?

Comment: @Alexandera: No. Alice encrypted the packet with Bob's key in the first place, so only Bob can get the decrypted contents. The last node decrypts the packet with its key and finds inside another encrypted packet which it forwards to Bob. It has no idea what's inside that encrypted packet since it doesn't have Bob's key. So far as the node talking to Bob knows, he might be the final destination or he might unwrap another encrypted packet he sends to someone else. And, of course, that node has absolutely no idea who the originator is.

Comment: @ David Schwartz Thank you for your reply. It is a great help. One last question, alright we send the query message from requester(Alice) to sender(Bob who has the file), and through mixes, we achieve this, what about reply path? Since Bob(sender) would be sending the requested content to requester(Alice). And also when Alice receives  the file from Bob,it would be encrypted?We don't to apply need end to end encryption?

Comment: @Alexandera: Alice includes her public key (which can be one she just created only for this communication if that's what she wants) in the communication to Bob. This ensures only Alice can decrypt the content (unless Bob chooses to let others see it, of course). As for securing the path, Alice constructs the return path hop-by-hop, instructing each hop how to use the rest of the path to get packets back to her. Again, all those nodes would have to conspire to compromise her location. Each node does not know what Alice has set up behind it.

Comment: @Alexandera: In other words, Alice sets up a secure connection to A. Then using that secure connection, sets up a secure connection from A to B, where A uses the secure connection to get its end to her. Then using that, she builds a secure connection from B to C, such that B hooks up its end of that connection to the pipe between A and B. And so on, eventually hooking up to Bob. B knows the connection comes from C and goes to A, but that's it. Bob knows the connection goes to C, and that's it. And so on.

Comment: @ David Schwartz We don't to apply need end to end encryption for data confidentiality?

Comment: @Alexandera: Of course we do. The first thing Bob does with any message he sends to Alice is encrypt it with her public key so only she can decrypt it. Everything else comes after that first step. (And, in fact, each step does that. When B sends a message back to A, it first encrypts it with A's public key because A and B may not be directly connected.)

Comment: @ David Schwartz What if ,instead of end to end encryption and onion routing, we have a proxy between Alice and Bob. Alice requests a Proxy  who makes connection with Bob and Bob transfers the file to proxy.If we manipulate the file e.g some permutation etc(coming from Bob to proxy) so that when proxy gets the file, he has the permuted file contents, along with file Bob also transfers the secret information through proxy to Alice so that she can do the same manipulation to get the same content. In this way,proxy will not be able to get the file contents. Is this possible?

Comment: @Alexandera: How is that different? That's saying that Bob encrypts the file such that Alice can decode it. The encryption is still end-to-end -- bob encrypted it, only Alice decrypts it.

Comment: How does the message get to Bob if even Alice doesn't know who (and where) Bob is?

Comment: @Alexandera: Even after reading the whole comment exchange, I still don't understand the question. Could you edit the question so it is more clear in what situation your Alice and Bob are?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Bob sets up a well-known rendezvous point the same way Alice sets up the return path, building it up hop-by-hop. The first hop has no idea it's talking to Bob and no idea it's the first hop. The last hop has no idea who the first hop is. (The last hop, of course, knows the path goes to Bob and that it's the last hop, that's how Alice finds a path to Bob.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: The scenario is as below.              Consider a P2P network in which Alice is the requester and Bob is one of the providers. Alice is requesting segments of file from different providers. But to simplify it here, I am just considering that Alice is requesting from Bob. But We have to provide the mutual anonymity here such that Alice doesn't know she is getting content from Bob and Bob does not know who is requesting the content(i.e. Alice). I hope it is clear now?